# cron is not restarting pm2

Tags: cron, pm2

I've tried many things but cron just won't restart pm2.
I set the `crontab -e` with:

```
SHELL=/bin/sh PATH=/bin:/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin

*/10 * * * *  /usr/bin/node /usr/bin/pm2 restart all
```

And the I type:

```
cat /var/log/cron.log
```

And it says:

```
Apr  2 01:00:01 fatsecret CRON[8202]: (peteblank) CMD (/usr/bin/node /usr/bin/pm2 restart all)
Apr  2 01:00:01 fatsecret CRON[8201]: (peteblank) MAIL (mailed 78 bytes of output but got status 0x004b from MTA#012)
Apr  2 01:10:01 fatsecret CRON[8454]: (peteblank) CMD (/usr/bin/node /usr/bin/pm2 restart all)
Apr  2 01:10:01 fatsecret CRON[8453]: (peteblank) MAIL (mailed 78 bytes of output but got status 0x004b from MTA#012)
```

So it looks like its restarting every 10 minutes, but its not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So it turns out pm2 has an inbuilt cron feature. So I ran

```
pm2 restart 0 --cron "*/10 * * * *"
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way to deal with `cron` jobs is to create specific script like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

. ~/.bashrc
/usr/bin/node /usr/bin/pm2 restart all
```

This script will load the environment variables which are required to run `node`
and run the script in cron:

```
*/10 * * * *  /path/to/script
```

Do not forget to change `~/.bashrc` with the absolute path to this file